# Using async data for seo head elements in nuxt3

Tags: html, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3, directus

I am trying to create a site using data fetched from a directus instance.

Currently I have a layout component `app.vue` filling all seo meta tags using static default values hardcoded in that file.

So in the setup I am using:

```js
useSeoMeta({
  title: () => "Static title"
})
```

which is not creating the desired output. No title is rendered.

Also for a post component I want to overwrite the values from layout using data fetched from a remote source:

```js
const { data: post, pending } = await useAsyncData('post', () => {
  return getItemById({
    collection: "collection_id",
    filter: {
      status: "published"
    },
    id: route.params.id,
  }).then((data) => {
      let ast = Markdoc.parse(data.content);
      let transform = Markdoc.transform(ast);
      data.content = Markdoc.renderers.html(transform);
    
      useSeoMeta({
        title: data.seo_title,      
      });

      return data;
  });
});
```

This is also not working as expected and serves different result, depending weather ssr is applied or not.

How would one implement a solution like this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? Or get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I found out best way to define SEO tags with ssr data is using [Nuxt built-in components](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#components).

```js
<template>
 <div>
  <Title>{{data.seo_title}}</Title>
 </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
const { data, pending } = await useAsyncData('post', () => {
  return getItemById({
    collection: "collection_id",
    filter: {
      status: "published"
    },
    id: route.params.id,
  })
});
</script>
```